# Adding a user using fetch with POST method

Tags: javascript, post, fetch

Using the following code, I'm trying to add a new user and console log all users including the new added one:

```
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

// Creating a user
fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: "Robert Miller",
    username: "robby",
    email: "roby@outlook.com"
  }),
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log(response));
```

However, the console.log shows only the added user but not all users.
My assumption was that because the method of the fetch is POST, I need to send another request via GET to get all users and came up with this:

```
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

// Creating a user
fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: "Robert Miller",
    username: "robby",
    email: "roby@outlook.com"
  }),
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log(response));
  fetchAllUsers();


function fetchAllUsers() {
fetch(url)
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    // Read the response as json.
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    // Do stuff with the JSON
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Looks like there was a problem: \n", error);
  });
}
```

But I still cannot see the added user in the list. Any help?

Comment: The documentation for that site doesn't say anything about adding users.

Comment: Hmm, that might be the reason. Is there any other API page, which I could use for testing fetch with POST?

Comment: Call `fetchAllUsers();` inside the `fetch` for adding a user and then you should get all your users, including the added one. Of course, all that if that API allows you to insert users.

Comment: @user1941537 I'm afraid I have no idea; that tool is nice for what it is but it's pretty limited.

Answer (score -3):

I think this link is answer your question:
[Unable to post a new user](https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder/issues/78)

Since JSONPlaceholder is a shared API used by many, modifications are faked (POST, PUT, PATCH) and resources are read-only. This is to avoid user "A" creating new resources and having user "B" impacted by them.

If you need to make changes and persist them between calls, you can run JSON Server locally.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)